# Plane tracker in viewport

Tags: cycles-render-engine, motion-capture

I have tried to place a phone in the hand with object tracker and it just doesnt line up when rotating etc,

if i use the plane tracker the plane track is perfect, but i cant find any option to export my plane tracker to the 3d viewport. Is there any way to do it?

If i could export the plane tracker to my 3d viewport i could align my mesh to that plane and it should be perfect